# Using the same node twice

Tags: ros, c++, namespace

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hellows,

Another designing question under ROS. I have a node that I programmed, it used param from the Param Server and subscribe to a topic and publish two topics.

I wish to launch to node twice using a launch file. All my parameters arr in yaml file. But I can't find any way for the code in C++ to go search the parameters in two different namespace without compiling two executable with just the namespace of difference in the `getParam()` function and it really is not optimal.

For now my function look like :

```
my_node.param<std::string>("/namespace1/source",source, "camera/rgb/image");
```

Is there any way to not need the name space hard coded ?

[EDIT]

I'll try to be more precise :).

For example I use the  tag to remap the topic that are given by the two nodes. So I have "topic1" and "topic2". That is ok.

But now I want to publish parameters which have the same name but associated to each node. Let's say a parameter name /source for each of the node but under the namespace Node1/source, Node/source. This can be done with the launch file, I just need to load two yaml file or so.
But now for now, my code to get in the param in my C++ code is like this

```
my_node.param<std::string>("/Node1/source",source, "camera/rgb/image");
```

for the first one

```
my_node.param<std::string>("/Node2/source",source, "camera/rgb/image");
```

for the second one.

I'm wondering if there is a way to right

```
my_node.param<std::string>("/source",source, "camera/rgb/image");
```

And the node would understand by itself that it's either Node1/source or Node2/source that they need.

Hope I have been clearer.
Thanks a lot =)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/146486/using-the-same-node-twice/) by [Maya](https://answers.ros.org/users/12786/maya/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1172 on 2014-03-31

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-03-31**:
It's definitely possible. Can you be more concrete on what your resulting setup should look like, i.e. which topics would you like to have for each node and where should the names come from? It looks to me as if you might not need any parameters and can do everything from launch files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is this about each node accessing it's own parameters (not another node's)? In that case you should use 'private parameters' such that your code is agnostic about the actual node name and even additional layers of namespaces:

http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Parameter%20Server#Accessing_Private_Parameters

---

Originally posted by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) with karma: 4306 on 2014-03-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Maya](https://answers.ros.org/users/12786/maya/) on 2014-03-31**:
I used private parameters. This is exactly what I was searching for for. Thanks @demmeln and @dornhege

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Fix that:

```
my_node.param<std::string>("/source",source, "camera/rgb/image");
```

to (no "/"!)

```
my_node.param<std::string>("source",source, "camera/rgb/image");
```

If your my_node nodehandle is a private nodehandle, it will load the different private parameters.

Given that this looks like a parameter for a topic, there are probably better ways to do this that do not require loading parameters at all.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2014-03-31

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Maya](https://answers.ros.org/users/12786/maya/) on 2014-03-31**:
I'll use the same syntax for other parameter like where to load a model.
For the topic parameter I will change it to a default value that need to be remap in the launcher would it be better ?

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-03-31**:
That's usually the simpler way.